# Hello, I'm trying to convert from YYYY/MM/DD to dd/mm/yyyy by using .strptime but it comes up with AttributeError: object has no attribute 'strptime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, datetime

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
import datetime
import time
import math
seconds_Yearly = 3656060*24
seconds_Daily = 606024
seconds_Hourly = 60*60
minute = 60
eventName1 = input("What is the name of the first event?")
print(" ")
eventName2 = input("What is the name of the second event?")
print(" ")
event_Year1 = input("Which year is" + " " + str(eventName1) + " " + "in?")
print(" ")
event_Month1 = input("Which month [1-12] is" + " " + str(eventName1) + " " + "in?")
print(" ")
event_Day1 = input("Which day [1-31] is" + " " + str(eventName1) + " " + "in?")
print(" ")
event_Year2 = input("Which year is" + " " + str(eventName2) + " " + "in?")
print(" ")
event_Month2 = input("Which month [1-12] is" + " " + str(eventName2) + " " + "in?")
print(" ")
event_Day2 = input("Which day [1-31] is" + " " + str(eventName2) + " " + "in?")
print(" ")
event_Year1 = int(event_Year1)
event_Month1 = int(event_Month1)
event_Day1 = int(event_Day1)
event_Year2 = int(event_Year2)
event_Month2 = int(event_Month2)
event_Day2 = int(event_Day2)
event1_dates = date((event_Year1), (event_Month1), (event_Day1))
event1_date = event1_dates.strptime((event_Year1), (event_Month1), (event_Day1), "d/m/Y")
print(str(event1_date))
print(" ")
event2_date = date((event_Year2), (event_Month2), event_Day2)
print(event2_date)
print(" ")
seconds_event1 = time.mktime(event1_date.timetuple())
print(seconds_event1)
print(" ")
seconds_event2 = time.mktime(event2_date.timetuple())
print(seconds_event2)
print(" ")
seconds_difference_rough = seconds_event2 - seconds_event1
seconds_difference = abs(seconds_difference_rough)
print(seconds_difference)
print(" ")
minutes_difference = seconds_difference/60
print(minutes_difference) 
print(" ")
hours_difference = minutes_difference/60
print(hours_difference)
print(" ")
days_difference_rough = hours_difference/24
days_difference = abs(days_difference_rough)
print(days_difference)
print(" ")
years_difference_roughs = seconds_difference/seconds_Yearly
years_difference_rough = seconds_difference//seconds_Yearly
years_difference = abs(years_difference_rough)
years_difference_remainer = seconds_difference%seconds_Yearly
print(years_difference)
print(years_difference_roughs)
weeks_difference_parta = (days_difference/7)/52
weeks_difference_partb = weeks_difference_parta/years_difference_roughs
weeks_difference = abs(weeks_difference_partb)
print(weeks_difference)
months_difference_part1a = hours_difference/24/30.435
months_difference_part1aa = months_difference_part1a//1
months_difference_part1b = abs(months_difference_part1aa)
print(months_difference_part1b)
months_difference_part2a = (years_difference * 12) - months_difference_part1b
month_difference_roughs = (years_difference * 12) - months_difference_part1a
months_difference_part2b = abs(months_difference_part2a)
days_decimal, whole = math.modf(months_difference_part1a)
print(" ")
print(months_difference_part2b)
print(" ")
print(months_difference_part1a)
print(" ")
days_difference1a = days_difference/28
days_difference1ab = days_difference/30.45
days_difference1b = days_difference1ab//1
days_difference1c = (days_difference1a - days_difference1ab)
days_difference_total = abs(days_difference1b)
print(days_difference_total)
print(" ")
print(days_difference1ab)
week_difference = days_difference_total/7
week_difference_total = abs(week_difference)
print(week_difference_total)
print(" ")
#hours_one = hours_difference
```

```py
def days ():
    global days, days_remaing_negative, days_remaing_positve, days_remaing
    if event_Year2 > event_Year1:
        months_difference_rough = days_difference/(hours_difference/24/30.435)
        months_difference = abs(days_difference_rough)
        months_difference_remainer = seconds_difference%seconds_Daily
        print(months_difference)
        print(days_decimal)
        days_remaings = (days_decimal * 30.435) + 1
        days_remaing = days_remaings//1
        days_remaing = abs(days_remaing)
        print(days_remaing)
    else:
        days_remaings = (days_decimal * 30.435) + 1
        days_remaing = days_remaings//1
        print(days_remaing)
```

```py
def weeks():
    global days_remaing, days, new_week, new_days2
    if days_remaing >= 7:
        new_weeks = days_remaing/7
        abs_new_week = abs(new_weeks)
        new_week = new_weeks//1
        new_week_decimal, whole = math.modf(abs_new_week)
        new_days1 = new_week_decimal * 7
        new_days2 = new_days1//1
        print(new_week)
        print(new_days2)
    else:
        new_week = 0
        new_days2 = days_remaing
        print(new_days2)
```

```py
def difference():
    global new_days2, new_week, months_difference_part1b, years_difference, eventName1, eventName2, days_remaing, days, new_week, months_difference_part2b
    if event_Year2 > event_Year1 or event_Year2 == event_Year1 and event_Month2 > event_Month1:
        print("a")
        print(str(eventName1) + " "+  "is" + " " +  str(years_difference) + "years" + " "+ str(months_difference_part2b
        ) + "months" + " " + str(new_week) + "weeks" + " " + str(new_days2) + "days" + "  " + "before" + " " + str(eventName2))
    elif event_Year2 == event_Year1 and event_Month2 > event_Month1:
        print("b")
        print(str(eventName1) + " "+  "is" + " " +  str(years_difference) + "years" + " "+ str(months_difference_part2b
        ) + "months" + " " + str(new_week) + "weeks" + " " + str(new_days2) + "days" + " " + "before" + " " +  str(eventName2))
    elif event_Year2 == event_Year1 and event_Month2 == event_Month1 and event_Day2 > event_Day1:
        print("C")
        print(str(eventName1) + " "+  "is" + " " +  str(years_difference) + "years" + " "+ str(months_difference_part2b
        ) + "months" + " " + str(new_week) + "weeks" + " " + str(new_days2) + "days" + " " + "before" + " " + str(eventName2))
    else:
        print("D")
        print(str(eventName1) + " " +  "is" + " " + "on" + " " + str(event1_date) + " " + " " + "which is" + str(years_difference) + "years" + " "+ str(months_difference_part2b
        ) + "months" + " " + str(new_week) + "weeks" + " " + str(new_days2) + "days" + " " + "After" + " " + " " + str(eventName2))
```

```
days ()
weeks()
difference()
```

Comment: please only use a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show where you are stuck. Show the line where the error occurs and the full Traceback.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Are you trying to convert event1_dates?

```
from datetime import date

event_Year1=2020
event_Month1=1
event_Day1=30

event1_dates = date((event_Year1), (event_Month1), (event_Day1))
print(event1_dates)
event1_date = event1_dates.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
print(event1_date)
```

Output:

```
2020-01-30
30/01/2020
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I only started last week and all.